# Jquery: table rows are not draggable when number of rows are many

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my jquery for making table rows draggable. The problem is when number of rows are more than 200, it slows down drastically.

```
var fixHelperModified = function(e, tr) {
      var $originals = tr.children();
      var $helper = tr.clone();
      $helper.children().each(function(index) {
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width())
      });
      return $helper;
  },
      updateIndex = function(e, ui) {
          $('td.index', ui.item.parent()).each(function (i) {
              $(this).html(i + 1);
          });
      };

  $("#table_testSuite tbody").sortable({
      helper: fixHelperModified,
      stop: updateIndex
  }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Might want to add `items` option.

Comment: Please give an example of *more*, 15? 500? 10,000? More than what?

Comment: its slow for more than 200 rows